# put the content of a single post into og:description

Tags: the-content

I'd like to have the content of the current single post loaded into the og:description meta property - but the `'. $content .'` doesn't output anything?

This is what's in my header.php

```
if (is_single()) {

$content = get_the_content();
$desc='<meta property="og:description" content="'. $content .'" />';
echo $desc;
}
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: "The description should provide a concise summary of the page in approximately 200 characters or fewer."

Comment: see: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/facebook-page-publish/trunk/fpp_index.php ; add_action('wp_head', 'fpp_head_action');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_the_content()` must be inside [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), in header.php you can do this (don't forget to scape the content to use it as attribute):

```
 if (is_single()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $content = get_the_content();
        $desc='<meta property="og:description" content="'. esc_attr($content) .'">';
        echo $desc;
    }
 }
```

or even better, in your functions.php hook the wp_head action; also, I recomend using the excerpt instead of the content as descriptoin. (note the use of global $post and [setup_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)).

```
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_wp_head' );
 function my_wp_head() {
     if (is_single()) {
         $post_id = get_queried_object_id():
         $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $post_id );
         $desc = '<meta property="og:description" content="Blabla'. esc_attr( $excerpt ) .'">';
         echo $desc;
      }
      //More stuff to put in <head>
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

See the codex page for [`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content):

> **Description**
>   Retrieve the post content. (Must be used in a Loop)

Emphasis on »**Must be used in a Loop**«.

---

**Edit:**

To give you a possible solution, you can use [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post), for pages and posts, like shown below, to get the post content outside the loop.

```
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
$post_obj = get_post( $post_id );
$content = $post_obj->post_content;
```

---

**Update:**

There is a pretty interesting comparison by Peter Knight regarding the [Differences between using get_post() and WP_Query()](http://www.peterrknight.com/differences-between-using-get_post-and-wp_query/). I can't replicate it all, but basically it boils down to: performance and amount of available data. A short not at all conclusive and complete aggregation could be: on the one hand, with `WP_Query` you have the meta data too, not the case with `get_post`, but on the other hand, with `WP_Query` there are four database queries, whereas you have one database query using `get_post`. So there definitely are some differences to consider, read the article for more information, which method is right depends on what is needed for the actual use case on hand.

Comment: This i imagine, is precisely the problem. +1